Quasi-polarity behavior of silicon capacitor that then reverses when put in use?
What could cause a silicon capacitor to start behaving like a quasi-polar capacitor?
A filter involves two 100pF SMD silicon capacitors(600S101FT250T).  Two such filters (for two channels) are pictured below:

I noticed that the top filter (2* components) works but the bottom one wasn't working.  So I probed until I isolated C15 as the apparent "culprit" because of the following traces driven by the same 5.2MHz sine -- with polarity reversed between the two:

Reversed:

When I desoldered, reversed and resoldered C15 things seemed to work at first and then the signal out of that channel went dead again.
Investigating, I found C15 had reverted to the same state.
The other capacitors also exhibited polarity in the same way but reversed, ie: they didn't seem to change polarity after use.
I'm not sure but I think this happens when I switch the CCFL's to AC (50kHz ballast) after running DC (full wave rectified from the ballast).

Incidental: I don't see where they actually say they are "silicon" capacitors; they may be regular C0G (CaZrO3 or relatives). Kyocera does offer a line of silica (SiO2) capacitors (Accu-P(R)), but they don't say any others are. It's perplexing why at least one supplier has labeled this part as "silicon". Strange.
